# Regex array (["number", "number",...])

Tags: ruby, regex

Can you help me with expression for array: `["232","2323","233"]`
I try this: `/^\[("\d{1,7}")|(,"\d{1,7}")\]$/`
But this expression is not working properly.
I use ruby(rails).

Comment: what is the expected output || what do you want to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would validate the array structure well, blocking an entry like `[,"123"]`

```
^\[(("\d{1,7}")(,"\d{1,7}")*)?\]$
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this ( though it may allow leading `,`):

```
^\[(,?"\d{1,7}")*]$
```

Comment: Why a `,` before the opening `"` and after the closing `"`?

Comment: @NaveedS - Unintentionally added. My description was right, but forgot to remove one of the `,`

Comment: Note this may capture an empty array as well.

Comment: @YamMarcovic empty array is allowed I think.
@manojlds I suggest a correction `^\[(("\d{1,7}")(,"\d{1,7}")*)?\]$` as it validates the array well. My suggestion for the edit was rejected.

Comment: @NaveedS And perhaps even more functional. :) Was just stating a fact to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `/^\[("\d{1,7}")(, ?"\d{1,7}")*\]$/`